# TILED editor - object placement possible to snap to grid in Object Layer?

Tags: oop, tiled, tmx

thanks again in advance for any time spent helping me.

Thankfully, I have been able to import TMX to libgdx game without much of a problem, however this is now the first time of using Object Layer, for which at this moment in time I only want to include Platforms as the object (ie. I have 1x Tile Layer showing my background image and 1x Object Layer above). Now I've seen that I can just draw lines and/or boxes, circles etc to create 'zones' which I can pull into my code (goodness only knows how atm but I'll figure that later/soon )

But I see in Tiled that the button - Insert Tile (T) - exists.
I'm trying to use it but when the tile im using as a platform is placed it goes exactly where the mouse is pressed and I can't move it other than delete it. I'd just like to copy-paste a whole row of them for now and Level1 can just be 50 tiles in a flat line just so I can get it all working. It seems weird to me that Tiled can't do this but Ive spent ages looking for a way and can't find it.

Am I missing something or is this just not possible? And if the latter, how does an experienced tiled user (who's making a 2d platformer) go about creating such a simple example above in the Tiled environment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What a noob - I answered my own question. The option I needed was in the 'View' dropdown menu -> 'Snap To grid' LOL

Comment: I'm a big noob myself. Needed to google this feature xD

Comment: In the current version of Tiled: "View" > "Snapping" > "Snap to Grid". Your answer now is at the top of Google searching. Thank you!

Comment: You can snap to a grid on an object layer in two additional ways: 1) hold Ctrl as you begin to draw the object, or 2) hold Alt as you resize the object.